# Access to fetch at ’http://localhost:8000/api/user-context' from origin ‘http://localhost:3500’ has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: reactjs, cors, next.js

I want to setup NEXT JS based application on port other than 3000. Right now whenever I change the port it stops responding.

next build && ./node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 start npm --name $NEXT_NAME -- start -i 1

Access to fetch at ’http://localhost:8000/api/user-context' from origin ‘http://localhost:3500’ has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn’t pass access control check: The ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header has a value ‘http://localhost:3500/’ that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque response serves your needs, set the request’s mode to ‘no-cors’ to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: You have the server configured with the value `http://localhost:3500/` — with a trailing slash `\` character. Remove that trailing slash. Origin values can’t have a trailing slash. Change he value to `http://localhost:3500` — with no trailing slash.

Answer (score 0):

**Preferred Solution:**

In your API server you can enable CROS. You can read this details given on [this](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled) link to enable CROS in your server.

Example for ExpressJS:

```
app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
    next()
});
```

**Temporary Solution:**

You can install the following browser extensions to fix this temporary.

- [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)
- [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/)

Comment: res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
The above statement will open access to all URL's. We want to restrict access to particular port.

Comment: Then in this case you can replace `*` with your URL. Ex: `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3500");`